# Should I really get frequent collisions with bcrypt?

Tags: security, cryptography, collision, bcrypt

When hashing two random strings, I get on average 2 collisions out of 100,000.
Is this expected?

All of these strings produce the same hash (using any salt and any work factor):

```
base64_decode('/g=');
base64_decode('/gB/==');
base64_decode('/gBQyVY/0dzg');
base64_decode('/gBQyoK71jVY/JZP0dzg=');
base64_decode('/gBQyoK71jVY/J2ea4q9mAZP0dzg==');
base64_decode('/gBQyoK71jVY/J7QuBNJuFdxyf2eTBCs42chkx6ZvpJYszpUcJk8/HXa4q9mAZP0dzg=');
```

And these are just examples, try adding and removing characters from the center, you get many more matches.
Here is the php code used to find them:

```
set_time_limit(60*10);
$salt = '$2a$04$usesomesillystringforsalt$';
for($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $one = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(rand(1,111));
    $two = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(rand(1,111));
    if(crypt($one, $salt)==crypt($two, $salt)){
        echo base64_encode($one).'|'.base64_encode($two)."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: These collisions are specific to php which uses openwall implementation of bcrypt I believe. jBCrypt produces different hashes for this data for some reason (different from php and different from each other).

Comment: This string is encoded differently by bcrypt in php and java: "þ"

Comment: Make sure the salt is encoded in the right way - PHP wants 22 digits in `[./0-9A-Za-z]` there, and you are passing 25 digits. Could it be that this is the cause?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Nope, the salt doesn't matter here(it gets automatically truncated), I've tried using 22 digits also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bcrypt broken in PHP? Can easily include any malicious payload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352718/bcrypt-broken-in-php-can-easily-include-any-malicious-payload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, PHP doesn't play well with strings having a null byte.
The PHP crypt function is **not** binary safe.