# Bcrypt broken in PHP? Can easily include any malicious payload

Tags: php, security, encryption, bcrypt, collision

Salt: can be anything.
Work factor: can be anything.
All of the following generate the same hash!

```
$pad = base64_decode('/gB=');
$data = array(
    'LegitimatePayload',
    'LaterSwitchedToMaliciousPayload',
    'Abracadabra',
    'hatIsGoingOn',
    'CanBeAlmostAnything',
);

foreach($data as $str){
    echo crypt($pad.$str, '$2a$04$AnySaltHere')."<br>\n";
}
```

Output:

```
$2a$04$AnySaltHere$$$$$$$$$$.m/QKi19jyBmSuP2VMcVuFRw.weCNRBa
$2a$04$AnySaltHere$$$$$$$$$$.m/QKi19jyBmSuP2VMcVuFRw.weCNRBa
$2a$04$AnySaltHere$$$$$$$$$$.m/QKi19jyBmSuP2VMcVuFRw.weCNRBa
$2a$04$AnySaltHere$$$$$$$$$$.m/QKi19jyBmSuP2VMcVuFRw.weCNRBa
$2a$04$AnySaltHere$$$$$$$$$$.m/QKi19jyBmSuP2VMcVuFRw.weCNRBa
$2a$04$AnySaltHere$$$$$$$$$$.m/QKi19jyBmSuP2VMcVuFRw.weCNRBa
```

Edit:
Here is a string that has the same first two bytes but has a different hash:
base64_decode('/gBQyoK71jVY/J7QuBNJuFdxyf2eTBCs42chkx6ZvpJYszpzg===')
If php stopped at first NUL byte, then how do you explain this?

Comment: Did you mean `base64_encode`?

Comment: Either you have discovered a bug no one else ever has, or it's your code. Hint, it's the 2nd one.

Comment: I also don't see how inserting a malicious payload makes sense here. `crypt` isn't designed for integrity checks. It's designed for password hashing. So even if it were broken in the way you claim, the only consequence would be: Don't choose a password starting with these characters.

Comment: Stop voting down the question! This vulnerability is not present in jBcrypt. And I do have strings that start the same way but produce different hashes.

Comment: Some languages use binary safe strings. It is well known that most php functions are not binary safe, and break for strings containing `\0`. So unless you demonstrate that then problem isn't just php stopping at the first `\0` char, the downvotes are deserved, IMO.

Comment: I really don't know why this question got so many downvotes. +1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All your strings have a prefix that will - when run through `base64_decode` - result in a `0xfe` character and a `0x00` character with the extra - varying - characters after the 0x00. Since standard crypt will stop at a `0x00` character, all your crypt calls only encrypt the `0xfe` character.

You can verify it by just calling

```
echo crypt("\376", '$2a$04$AnySaltHere')."<br>\n";
```

which will give the same result.

I'm assuming you used `base64_decode` by mistake meaning to actually call `base64_encode`.

Edit: As Roman points out, the string

```
"/gBQyoK71jVY/J7QuBNJuFdxyf2eTBCs42chkx6ZvpJYszpzg==="
```

will actually - despite the same prefix - crypt to something else entirely. This is due to that string actually being invalid base64 and base64_decode returning false. That results in the string crypt'ing to the same hash as the empty string does instead.

Comment: The crypt doesn't stop at NUL character, I have strings that start same as above but produce different hashes.

Comment: +1 this is the right answer. `\0` bytes are a PITA in PHP's link to the lowlevel functions, and even a security issue. The problem is that PHP keeps string content and length as separate things, while the typical libc call takes zero terminated strings.

Comment: Use `for ( $i=0;$i<strlen($pad);$i++ ) printf("0x%02x\n",ord($pad[$i]));` to see the actual bytes.

Comment: I commented on the security issues of this some time ago on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115559/exploitable-php-functions/5442372#5442372

Comment: Here is a string that starts the same way but has different hash:
base64_decode('/gBQyoK71jVY/J7QuBNJuFdxyf2eTBCs42chkx6ZvpJYszpzg===').
How do you explain this?

Comment: @Roman That string - ending with 3 equals signs - actually is invalid base64 so base64_decode returns false. It crypts to the exact same hash as the empty string does, try `echo crypt("", '$2a$04$AnySaltHere')."<br>\n";`

Answer (score 5):

You're not providing any valid base64 encoded strings, so base64_decode will probably just return false for all of your test cases, and thus it will encrypt them all the same. Why are you using base64_decode anyway?

Comment: To show that it works for binary data, I've edited the code for clarity.

Comment: You're not getting the point : you're providing strings that are *not* base64 encoded, and thus base64_decode will *always* return false. There is no vulnerability, it's just your code that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: They do not return false I assure you. I have verified this by writing the output to file and viewing via hex editor.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `base64_encode` and not `base64_decode`. the reason it all returns the same is because the result is always false.

Comment: Doesn't return false, I've checked. Returns different strings. Question edited for clarity.